# Cannot use Date and Time Picker in Office 2013

Tags: vba, datepicker, excel-2013

Since few days I have tried to apply this ActiveX to my Excel 2013.
I made small app for running reports in Excel and I need some way to pick start and end date.

Easiest way to do it was Date And Time Picker Control which is in %windir%\syswow64\mscomct2.ocx.
It worked perfectly at Windows 7 64-bit + Excel 2010 32-bit.

When I moved my project to other PC with Windows 7 64-bit and Office 2013 32-bit it stopped working. Firstly there was class missing, so I registered Microsoft Windows Common Controls 2 6.0 (SP3) in syswow64 using regsvr32.exe command.

It did not help - it was keep saying "cannot insert object".
Tried another versions of Common Controls (currently SP6), but problem is still there - I can`t put any control to my Excel worksheet.

I`m running out of ideas and tutorials, so maybe some of You had ran into this type of problem and have solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best that you just abandon your search for a Microsoft solution.  They haven't updated the common controls for 64-bit.  Your best options are to create your own ActiveX Control by wrapping the Date And Time Picker Control from .Net or [communicate using COM](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/) and expose the features that you want, or use one of the custom VBA solutions that can be found on **[Ron de Bruin's Calendar/Date Picker page](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s8/win003.htm)**.

I've used this one - [Calendar Control for All Office versions - including Office 2010 64 bit](https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50/calendar-control-class)

but this one looks better IMO - [A Pop-up Calendar for Excel 2007 and up](http://www.fontstuff.com/vba/vbatut07.htm)

Even if you can get it running on your machine, if you work at a large company, like myself, you'll never get IT to deploy the fix to everyone.

Edit: was getting confused with MSCOMCTL.OCX [issues](http://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/excel-vba-error-could-not-load-an-object-because-it-is-not-available-on-this-machine/)